# Merging big files in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, binary, append, exe, point

I want merge two file.
A file is a text file and is small but other is a video file and is large.
How i can merge this two files with low cost time?(first text file and then video file add to this text file)

[For Samples](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00763/46pbpbgilnj9.jpg)

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you think should a result look like when merging a text and a video file?

Comment: I want create lock software.i want insert a data binary at front of a big data.

Comment: Check BinaryReader especially function [ReadBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Binary Writer](https://www.google.de/search?q=create+binary+file+.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=OHQDV8vLN8bw6ASjvJf4DQ)

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend but time cost is very deep!i (force read video and append it to text file.)